# Consuming multiple topics of multiple Kafka brokers in Flink

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am using flink-1.4.2 with scala and I want to consume multiple data stream sources of Kafka. I have used union function of combine them but I am able to use one kafka source.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val kProps = new Properties()
    kProps.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "kafka01.prod.com:9092")
    kProps.setProperty("group.id", "test_cg")
    kProps.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "true")
    kProps.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
    val kProps2 = new Properties()
    kProps2.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "kafka04.prod.com:9092")
    kProps2.setProperty("group.id", "test_cg_2")
    kProps2.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "true")
    kProps2.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
    val sink = new BucketingSink[SimpleKafkaOutputMsg]("s3://some-bucket/")
    sink.setBucketer(new DateTimeBucketer[SimpleKafkaOutputMsg]("yyyy-MM-dd-HH"))
    sink.setWriter(new StringWriter[SimpleKafkaOutputMsg])
    sink.setBatchSize(350 * 1024 * 1024) // 350 MB
    sink.setPendingPrefix("file-")
    sink.setPendingSuffix(".csv")

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)
    env.setParallelism(9)
    env.setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend("file:///tmp/flink/checkpoints", false))
    val topics = List("ROUNDTRIP1")
    val inpStream1 = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer011(topics.asJava, new IndexedSectorMessagDes(), kProps))

    val topics2 = List("ROUNDTRIP2")
    val inpStream2 = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer011(topics2.asJava, new IndexedSectorMessagDes(), kProps2))

    val inpStream = inpStream1.union(inpStream2)
    .filter(new InvalidFlightsFilterFunction())
    .map(attachUID(_))
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new IngestionTimeExtractor[IndexedSectorMessage]())
    val intStream = inpStream.flatMap { s => flattenFlights(s) }
    intStream.keyBy(getFlightKey _).process(new KeyedWindowTimeMedianFunction()).addSink(sink)
    env.execute("Scala WindowExample Example")`
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are facing in more detail? Is the union of streams not consuming from multiple topics?

Comment: We are having two different kafka broker clusters and from each kafka broker cluster, we need to consumer different kafka topic. So, we have created two different input streams with different kafka broker cluster and we have done union to combine two  input streams but it is able to connect with one kafka broker cluster.

Comment: Are you able to ping the second broker cluster from the machine where you are running Flink? What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Yes, I am able to.